# Find loaded php.ini from command line

Tags: php, apache, command-line, virtualmin

I am on a server with multiple domains. I would like to find out which `php.ini` gets loaded in each domain.
I've got a few different tools at hand. Perhaps they get me closer to what I want.

1. A simple `php -i|grep 'Loaded Configuration File'` returns the system `php.ini`.
2. `find /home/ -xdev -name php.ini 2>/dev/null` returns all `php.ini` belonging to all hosted domains.
3. `virtualmin list-php-directories --domain this.is.a.domain --multiline` returns all directories in which a specific version of PHP has been activated.

Some sample output:
1. Returns:

```
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

This is obviously the `php.ini` which gets loaded by the host OS.
2. Returns:

```
...
/home/domain.x.com/etc/php5/php.ini
/home/domain.x.com/etc/php7.0/php.ini
/home/domain.x.com/etc/php.ini
/home/domain.y.com/etc/php7.0/php.ini
/home/domain.y.com/etc/php.ini
...
```

This is a complete list of all `php.ini` in those domains.
3. Returns:

```
/home/domain.x.com/public_html
  PHP version: 7.0
  Full version: 7.0.8
  Execution mode: fcgid
  Web root directory: Yes
```

There is always a `php.ini` in `/home/domain.foo.com/etc/`. Is that the one that hets loaded? Or do I have to check `virtualmin` for which version of PHP is loaded to traverse into the appropriate subdir? Is there a completely different way?

**Note**: I only have the command line at hand and only one user for monitoring purposes. Also, the process should be non-invasive. So I dont' think that I can put some php files in those domains to get my answer through a browser. Is the info perhaps stored in some file I can parse?

Comment: `php --ini` ? It will show you in details all the PHP.ini paths specifying which is loaded. Not sure how this will work for multiple domains, but worth a try.

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question! What is the output of command number 2 above? Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Also check if you have a real file or just a symlink to another real file!

Comment: And php function  `php_ini_loaded_file()`. Also there are 3 `php.ini` in use, always, one for CLI one for CGI and one for WEB. Sometimes they point via `symlink` to one real `php.ini`. Under linux you can do `locate php.ini` and you well see all you have on the hardware.

Comment: @MarinNedea this returns only info for the host OS.

Comment: @KanadGodse Command 2 returns all `php.ini`. Not which is actually loaded.

Comment: Well, then please see my answer below, you can get the exact php.ini which is loaded from each domain by doing that.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions that return the same result as Command 1

Comment: `that`? I have dropped 2 comments?!? Keep in mind via command line there is not the same php.ini used as if you test it via browser. Use `php_ini_loaded_file()` in you php script, load the page from webbrowser, then check if the used `php.ini` is a symlink to another on the hardware.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions ahh. right. From a browser this will be different. My question stated, that I can only use the command line.

Comment: But `in each domain` sounds like you want to know, whats loaded when accessed via web-browser, too me ;-) Like the answer below :-)

Comment: Yes. That is what I want to do. I know that I can do it in the way described in the answer below. It just could be that I dont have that option to put some file in each domain. So I was wondering if the information is listed in some file I could parse without tinkering with the filesystem of the customers.

Answer (score 1):

From only the command line, you would need to:

1. Install a command line web browser OR you can use wget to hit the script and save the response in a file.
2. Have a php file with `<?php phpinfo();` in all of the domains
3. Make sure that all the domains are able to be loaded on the webserver or the webserver has internet access to load the domains directly from web. Best would be to map all the domains to localhost in the hosts file.
4. Open the phpinfo script from each domain in the command line browser and check the loaded configuration file OR if you have chosen to use wget, just save the output to file and inspect the contents of the file and you would get the loaded config file.

Comment: This looks good. I will try this with wget when I get write access there. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: So you don't see a way to do this `read-only`? Is the info not stored in some file I could parse? Given that some of the domains belong to customers it is not so great to put some file in their domain.

Comment: I believe the php config path should be stored in the domain's vhost file if each domain is loading a custom php.ini file. Could you please check the server configuration files? 

From your question above, if you don't want to put files in your customer's domains, the 3rd command you mentioned should do the trick, but you would again be guessing and the only sureshot way to know would be to actually have a php page execute and show the config file location through `php-info()` as I have mentioned. Let me know if you need any help. Thanks!